# How to pass a config file to an imported React library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

### Problem

In order to make it easier to share code across projects, we created a *npm* component library. This will be it's own package, which can be installed via `npm i -S my-component-library`. The problem is that every project has it's own colors, links, ..., which makes it harder to share.

How can the external library access this config? I don't want to have to pass a config object as a `prop` to every component, as this would make it very cumbersome to use.

Is there a way for an external library to read a *json* file or maybe use something like context?

### Code

The components will be exported from the library like this in the *index.js* file:

```
export { default as AppText } from "./components/AppText.jsx";
```

The component would look like this:

```
const AppText = ({ children, style, bold, italic, ...textProps }) => {
  const config = useConfig(); // Somehow get the config here, maybe via hook?

  const textStyles = {
    fontSize: Platform.isPad ? 20 : Platform.OS == "ios" ? 15 : 13,
    lineHeight: Platform.isPad ? 24 : Platform.OS == "ios" ? 15 : 13,
    color: "black",
    fontFamily: config.fontNames[bold ? "bold" : italic ? "italic" : "regular"],
  };

  return (
    <Text selectable {...textProps} style={[textStyles, style]}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default AppText;
```

Comment: Have you considered something like a `ThemeProvider` like the [MUI ThemeProvider](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#theme-provider) or the [ChakraUI ThemeProvider](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme). These take in the **theme/config** needed for all the custom components and then as you mention use a hook to get the config and use it in the components.